# C++: converting WCHAR to LPCWSTR - real working example

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a situation where I need to convert this:

```
WCHAR path[260];
```

to:

```
LPCWSTR pathAfterConversion;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
LPCWSTR pathAfterConversion = path;
```

should work fine.

Note that `WCHAR` is actually `wchar_t` and `LPCWSTR` is actually `wchar_t const*`. Both are typedefs.

Answer (score 3):

```
pathAfterConversion = path;
```

No conversion necessary.

Comment: `const WCHAR*` and `LPCWSTR` are the same type, so array decay does the trick.

Comment: Pedantically, there is "conversion" involved. It is just "explicit" conversion which is not necessary here.

Comment: shouldn't this question have a windows tag, because i only ever saw those typedefs there?